# How can I unscrew a flashlight so I can change the batteries?

Tags: stuck

I bought a Coast g25 flashlight new 2 years ago. The batteries are dead so I need to replace them. But I can’t unscrew it. It just won’t budge. It’s not rusted, and hasn’t had any other damage that I can see.

First, which end of the flashlight should be unscrewed? I thought it was at the “back” end where the power button is, so I applied WD 40 and tried later and was successful. But the only thing I could see was the power button’s insides. No place for batteries. Should I try to pull this part out and maybe I’ll find the cavity where the batteries go?

The other possibility is the front end where the bulb is. It’s harder to see if there are actually two separate parts screwed together or not. There is a line going around the bulb area, which might be where the parts come together... or it could just be decor.  It won’t budge at all. I tried WD 40, but that didn’t help.

Any suggestions? Please tell me where the parts are screwed together so I won’t waste energy trying to unscrew something that’s a single, solid part.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about home improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I found these answers using Google:

Twist off the end where the switch is.

You unscrew the tail end of the flashlight, the part after the red ring. There are two AA batteries in the body of the handle.

The bottom screws off !

...to open the flashlight, twist the tail cap of the light counterclockwise.

Rotate the end cap.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I did unscrew the bottom, and it came off, but the red part, which looks like a red band when the bottom is attached, was still screwed into the rest of the flashlight. I tried to unscrew the red part, but I have no leverage because that section is so thin. I can’t get a grip around it. It did *not* come off with the rest of the bottom piece. I tried this wearing rubber gloves on both hands. I’d already applied WD 40 to that part of the flashlight. I also searched on google and didn’t find anything on the G25. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same light and the same issue. I found that I was able to remove the red ring with some serious pressure using channel locks, but the issue was from one of the batteries that corroded. I would guess if the battery had not disintegrated, it would have screwed right off.